# Структура базы данных, laravel

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры-данных

На сайте на разных страницах должен выводиться контент, редактируемый из админки.
И контент по своей структуре разный: на некоторых страницах нужно просто выводить кусочки текста в разных местах (заголовки), на других страницах нужно выводить большой текст, вместе с заголовками.
т.е. количество заголовков и другого контента динамически должно формироваться в админке.
Подойдёт ли такой вариант, что будет таблица `pages` с полями `id,name,slug`,
а также таблица для динамического добавления контента  `contents` с полями `id, content, type, position`
и связывающая таблица `pages_contents` с полями `page_id,content_id`?
А в админке на основе `id` текущей редактируемой страницы выбирать существующий контент или добавлять новый контент, привязанный к `id` странице.
В вёрстке выбирается контент текущей страницы по `id` и на основе полей `type` и `position` выводить в нужном месте.
Как правильно сделать структуру данных?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но не понятно, чем выбранная структура не устраивает?

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, со структурами баз работал ещё мало, поэтому спрашиваю совета. т.е. такой вариант подойдёт? А если связывающую таблицу не создавать, а в таблицу `contents` добавить поле `page_id`? так правильней?

Comment: и подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать про создание структур данных?

Comment: Да, верно: [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). В сети полно информации по реляционным базам данных, включая примеры конкретно Laravel - от миграций до CRUD.